# Null Pointer Exception while Autowiring LinkedBlockingQueue

Tags: spring, nullpointerexception, autowired

I am getting null pointer exception while trying to add anything in my solrQueue. I checked in debugger and it is because solrQueue is null. But I have autowired it in my application context then why this error?

```
public class Check {
    @Autowired
    public LinkedBlockingQueue<SolrInputDocument> solrQueue;
    public SolrInputDocument solrDoc;   
    public void solradd(){
        solrDoc=new SolrInputDocument();
        solrDoc.addField("title", "abc");
        solrQueue.add(solrDoc);//solrQueue is null 
    }
}
```

application Context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <!--<context:component-scan base-package="com/abc" />   -->

    <bean id="solrQueue" class="java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue" />
    <bean id="check" class="com.abc.Check" scope="prototype" />

</beans>
```

Comment: How do you obtain an instance of `Check` class? You are **not** calling `new Check()`, aren't you?

Comment: I am calling this function throvy groovy class where I have included the following code

Comment: Check c=new Check()
c.solradd()

Comment: Can we do autowiring in groovy class because I tried it also and getting NPE in the autowired Check class in my groovy file..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating an instance of `Check` class manually rather than asking Spring to create/return one for you:

```
Check c=new Check();
c.solradd();
```

This will never* work since Spring has no knowledge about you created `Check` class. Depending on how do you start you Spring context, you must either explicitly ask the application context:

```
Check check = applicationContext.getBean(Check.class)
```

or inject the `check` bean into some other compoent like controller:

```
@Autowired
private Check check;
```

### See also:

- [Spring Dependency Injection Autowiring Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091203)

<sup>* AspectJ weaving will do the trick, but this is like using a cannon to kill a fly</sup>

Comment: Thanks Tomasz..now i understood my mistake

Comment: @user598159: yes, the whole Grails platform is based on Spring.

Answer (score 0):

The reason lies here:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<!--<context:component-scan base-package="com/abc" />   -->
```

By including `annotation-config` you are allowing Spring to be using such extensions as `@Autowired` annotation. This, however, doesn't mean that Spring will know how to do that by itself.

For `@Autowired` to work, you need to have a matching bean defined in your application context. You can do that either manually (by placing `<bean>` declarations in XML) or automatically (by using `component-scan`).

**Solution**

try to uncomment `<context:component-scan />` and set proper `base-package`, matching the package of components you want to wire up automatically.

**Note**

if the components you want to wire are in third party library, it's usually more convenient to use an explicit `<bean class="com.somecompany.SomeComponent" />` definition within XML.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. but I didn't get u..I have explicitly included LinkedBlockingqueue bean..so I commented <context:component-scan> line..but I am also getting the similar error if I include the component scan line also.. :(

Comment: @ŁukaszBachman: the `solrQueue` bean is defined in XML, no context scanning is needed.

Comment: yup..but how to remove null pointer exception..It is  simple autowiring code

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz, how in hell have I missed that? :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can mix annotation and XML based config.
2 solutions here :

1. Remove the declaration of the Check bean in your XML file and add a `@Component` annotation on your Check class.
2. Inject the `solrQueue` property to your bean in the XML :

   `<bean id="check" class="com.abc.Check" scope="prototype">
   <property name="solrQueue" ref="solrQueue"/>
   </bean>`