# Spring bean not getting injected in Jboss

Tags: spring

I'm using JbossRestEasy hence i have used resteasy context loader listener in web.xml to load spring bean

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in spring configuration file

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.sample.MyBean">
    <property name="name" value="XYZ"/>
</bean>


public class Mybean{

    private String name;


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void printName(){
        System.out.println("Name is -->" +name);
    }
}
```

everything works fine if i specifically load the bean in my test case. but if i deploy it in jboss, bean is not getting injected. However, i could see that sprin config is getting loaded while server start up

```
12:43:40,626 INFO  [STDOUT] 12:43:40,626 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]
12:43:40,829 INFO  [STDOUT] 12:43:40,829 INFO  [DefaultListableBeanFactory] Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
```

It's very simple and straightforward but don't know wrong with my configuration. I'm using 3.0.5.RELEASE version of Spring.

Comment: How do you obtain an instance of this `MyBean` where you call `printName()`?

Comment: I'm just creating an instance of this class like Mybean bean=new MyBean(); in a client and trying to invoke the method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Dependency Injection Autowiring Null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091203/spring-dependency-injection-autowiring-null)

Comment: After changing all object as Spring bean, it worked. Thanks Tomasz