# JobExecution null in spring batch

Tags: scheduled-tasks, spring-batch

I am running jobs in parallel. My job execution is always null when I use `JobRepositoryFactoryBean`. I need to use to use this. If I don't use this, then I will not be able to use metadata tables. Because I want to restart my job when it is not completed because of some failure reason. So, I want previous record which I will be fetching from metadata tables. And if I use `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean`, the job execution is not null. But then there will not be insertion in metadata tables.
I referred this link:-

[My job is always null. Can't inject a batch job with Spring Batch. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681109/my-job-is-always-null-cant-inject-a-batch-job-with-spring-batch-why)

But the link is not working for me.

My congifuration is

`<bean id="batchScheduler" class="com.abc.BatchScheduler">
        <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher" />
        <property name="jobtwo" ref="JobTwo" />
</bean>`

I searched a lot. Please help me out. I am not able to proceed.

Comment: Show us your code and exception with stack trace

Comment: The problem is solved. But now I have some other issue. I want to start the job when the application is getting started. When jobA is running I am able to schedule jobB but not getting run. To do so, every time I need to stop and start the service. I have gone through many links which gives the solution of `SmartLifecycle` and `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>`. Is it right solution for me ? If so, I am not getting how to use them. Will you please tell me ?

Comment: How did you resolve the problem? @rucha