# Spring @Autowired variable is null inside of @Component

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Here is my component that contains `userService` auto wired. The problem is that is not initialized, always null. User service works fine from Controllers.

What should be done to autowire service inside of component?

```java
package com.boro.orange.component;

@Component("modelUtil")
public class ModelUtil {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService; //null

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ModelUtil.class.getName());

    public ModelMap warp(ModelMap model) {

        Object springUserObject = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if (springUserObject == null || !(springUserObject instanceof User)) {
            return model;
        }
        User springUser = (User) springUserObject;
        String userEmailAddress = springUser.getUsername();
        com.boro.orange.entity.User signedInUser = userService.getUserByEmailAddress(userEmailAddress);

        if (signedInUser == null) {
            String errorMsg = "Failed to find user by email address[" + userEmailAddress + "]";
            log.error(errorMsg);
            model.addAttribute("Error", errorMsg);
            // TODO add error messages
        } else {
            String userFirstName = signedInUser.getFirstName();
            String userLastName = signedInUser.getLastName();

            model.addAttribute("userFirstName", userFirstName);
            model.addAttribute("userLastName", userLastName);
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

`root-context.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.boro.orange.dao"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.boro.orange.service"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.boro.orange.component"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.boro.orange.controller"/>

    <import resource="data.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: Is there a Service annotation on UserService?  Can you add a Qualifier annotation?

Comment: @duffymo, yes, UserService works fine from other @ Controller classes.

Comment: Can't see what you've done wrong from this code.

Comment: How are you using the class `ModelUtil`? If you instantiate it yourself with `new ModelUtil()` then it's not a Spring managed bean and autowiring will not be done. See: [Spring Dependency Injection Autowiring Null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091203/spring-dependency-injection-autowiring-null)

Comment: Show the class where you call `warp`.

Comment: Ping me if this isn't the problem, because it looks like the classic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use only one definition for component scan. The last one overrides previous definitions.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.boro.orange"/>
```